# How to change MATLAB clustergram's axes start corners

Tags: matlab, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I generated below clustergram using `clustergram()` function in MATLAB 2016a. What I show is a correlation matrix, so the row and column labels are the same, but because of where MATLAB starts the axes, the block structure lies from topright to bottomleft, while I want it to lie from topleft to bottomright (which is how we usually show the blocks in a matrix). How can I achieve that? I checked the parameters of clustergram() function but I could not see any parameters to change the axes start corners.

I am fine with not having the dendrograms, as long as the labels are clustered according to the correlation values.

Here is my code to generate the clustergram:

```
cgo = clustergram(corr(values));
```

I also add the row and columns labels (which are not shown in the picture) using:

```
set(cgo, 'RowLabels', labels);
set(cgo, 'ColumnLabels', labels);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my own solution. I added below code to the code in the question. This basically gets the ordering from the clustergram, closes it, and then uses the retrieved ordering to create a heatmap using `imagesc()`, since `imagesc()` creates the matrix in the way I want it, as below:

```
ordering = get(cgo, 'RowLabels');
[~, ind] = ismember(get(cgo, 'RowLabels'), labels);
close all hidden
colormap jet
imagesc(c(ind, ind))
set(gca, 'Ticklength', [0 0])
set(gca, 'YTick', 1:length(ind), 'YTickLabel', labels(ind));
```

[image]